# PHP Calculating with time with a negative start value

Tags: php, excel, datetime, time

I'm trying to convert a certain excel sheet to a php app.
Within the excel sheet you could do time calculations as eg:

---

A starting time A1 (could be negative), and for every day you add or substract a certain amount of hours and minutes.

```
 - A1= -10:59 
 - A2= -7:36 
 - A3= -18:35 (A1 + A2)
   
 - B2= 4:24 
 - B3= -14:11 (A3 + B2)
```

And so on ...

---

Here is some code i've tested with without succes ofcourse...

```
    $startTime = new \DateTime('00:00:00');
    $startVal = new \DateInterval('PT10H59M');
    $startTime->sub($startVal); // -10:59:00

    $timeSpan = new \DateInterval('PT7H36M'); // 7:36:00
    $addTime = $startTime->add($timeSpan);
```

What is the best way to solve this in PHP? I've been testing around with DateTime but this won't allow me te start with a negative time value.

Hope someone can give me a hand.

Kind regards,
Jochem

Comment: I would convert time to seconds, sum them (depends the sign + or -) and after that convert to minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a simple class to handle this. It works for your given example but I was unable to test further as I cannot get negative times in my version of Excel. Let me know if it fails at some point.

```
class MyTime
{
  private $positive = true;
  private $hour=0;
  private $minute=0;

  /**
   * MyTime constructor.
   * Split the given time string into hours and minutes and whether it is positive or negative
   *
   * @param string $timeString In the format '-10:59', '4:35', or optionally just minutes '24'
   */
  public function __construct($timeString)
  {
    if(!empty($timeString))
    {
      if(strpos($timeString,'-')===0)
      {
        $this->positive = false;
        $timeString = substr($timeString,1);
      }

      $timeParts = explode(':',$timeString);
      if(!empty($timeParts))
      {
        if(count($timeParts) == 1)
        {
          $this->hour = 0;
          $this->minute = intval($timeParts[0]);
        }
        else
        {
          $this->hour = intval($timeParts[0]);
          $this->minute = intval($timeParts[1]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public function getHour()
  {
    return $this->hour;
  }

  public function getMinute()
  {
    return $this->minute;
  }

  /**
   * Convert into minutes either negative or positive
   * @return int
   */
  public function inMinutes()
  {
    $minutes = ($this->hour*60)+$this->minute;
    if(!$this->positive)
    {
      $minutes *= -1;
    }
    return $minutes;
  }

  /**
   * Convert back to a string for output
   * @return string
   */
  public function __toString()
  {
    return ($this->positive?'':'-').$this->getHour().':'.str_pad($this->getMinute(),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
  }

  /**
   * Add on the given time which could be negative
   * @param MyTime $time
   *
   * @return $this
   */
  public function add(MyTime $time)
  {
    $newMinutes = $this->inMinutes() + $time->inMinutes();
    if($newMinutes<0)
    {
      $this->hour = (int) ceil($newMinutes/60);
    }
    else
    {
      $this->hour = (int) floor($newMinutes/60);
    }
    $this->minute = abs($newMinutes-($this->hour*60));

    if($newMinutes<0)
    {
      $this->positive = false;
      $this->hour *= -1;
    }
    else
    {
      $this->positive = true;
    }
    return $this;
  }
}

$time = new MyTime('-10:59');
echo $time."\n";
echo $time->add(new MyTime('-7:36'))."\n";
echo $time->add(new MyTime('4:24'))."\n";
echo $time->add(new MyTime('18:32'))."\n";

$time = new MyTime('10:59');
echo $time."\n";
echo $time->add(new MyTime('-59'))."\n";
```

Comment: Hey Mark!

I'm realy thankfull for what you created! Much thanks!
However i stumbled up on a litle bug i guess. eg:

`$time = new MyTime('-24:59');
echo $time."\n";
echo $time->add(new MyTime('+12:00'))."\n";
echo $time->add(new MyTime('+12:00'))."\n";
echo $time."\n";`

This gives "0:59" but it should be "-0:59".

Any idea why this is ?

Comment: I have corrected the code. The problem was in the add function. After setting the new hour and minute I was checking if `$this->getHour()<0` and in your example it was exactly zero so the function made it positive even though there were some minutes to consider. I should have been checking the original `$newMinutes` result to see if it was less than zero. Let me know if you spot any other mistakes :)

Comment: Mark, i had found one more bug but did a small fix for it:
When the minutes where eg '08* minutes a decimal number would only set '8' as minutes:
i've added this bit of code to fix it, probable not the cleanest but it works.

In the Add function         

        `$minutes = abs($newMinutes - ($this->hour*60));
        $this->minute = strlen($minutes) == 1 ?  0 . $minutes : $minutes;`

Comment: If you've got it working that's fine but hours and minutes were supposed to remain as integer types until the class is converted to a string with __toString then it prepends the leading zero. This is because of all the calculations on them. I am not sure I understand the bug you mention nor what your fix is supposed to be doing. If you are converting $this->minutes into a string PHP will have to convert it back to an integer every time it needs it for a calculation.

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry for the bad explination, let me give you an example

        `$time = new MyTime('-6:32'); 
        echo $time."\n"; 
        echo $time->add(new MyTime('-7:36'))."\n"; 
        echo $time."\n";`

This time returns '-14:80' however it should be '-14:08'. Hope this clears out abit of the confusion

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have fixed the code. The correct place to fix that was in the `__toString()` function and not the `add()` function. As I say, `$this->minute` should remain as an integer. I simply added `STR_PAD_LEFT` in the `__toString()` function. Sorry for the mistake as it was quite obvious once you pointed it out :)

Comment: Hey Mark, you don't have to apologize! I'm realy thankfull for what you build here and everything seems to be working on point now ! 
Best regards, Jochem